# Linking button to new page in Django not working

Tags: html, django, django-forms

I have created an update view and am trying to link it to my form 
but the button linking doesn't seem to be working at all

urls.py

```
path('uploadupdate/<int:upload_id>', UploadUpdate.as_view(), name='uploadupdate'),
```

template:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Manage uploads</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'studyadmin/manageuploads_css.css' %}">
</head>

<body>
<table >
<tr class="main_row"> 
<th> Upload Name </th>
<th> Author Name </th>
<th> Type </th>
<th> Date </th>
<th> Edit </th>
<th>Edit Tags</th>

</tr>
<form >
{% csrf_token %}
{% for uploads in uploads %} <!-- shows all contents -->
<tr>
    <th> {{ uploads.title}} </th>
    <th> {{ uploads.author }} </th>
    <th> {{ uploads.upload_type }} </th>
    <th> {{ uploads.date_posted|date:"d M, Y"  }} </th>

    <th> <button href="{% url 'uploadupdate' uploads.upload_id  %}" type="submit" class="edit" formmethod="POST">Edit</button>  </th>
    <th> <button href="#" type="submit" class="edittags" formmethod="POST" >Edit tags</button>  </th>

{% endfor %}
</form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
class UploadUpdate(UpdateView):
form_class = UploadEditForm
template_name = 'studyadmin/upload_update_form.html'
queryset = Uploads.objects.all()

def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    obj = Uploads.objects.get(upload_id=self.kwargs['upload_id'])
    print(obj)
    return obj

def form_valid(self, form):
    upload = form.save(commit=False)
    upload.save()
    return redirect('/manageupload/')
```

I added the relevant code, I feel like its a small error but I can't seem to identify it since I'm very new to Django, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: where is your <form> HTML tag?

Comment: @Dalvtor it's higher up in my form , i only posted relevant information to it, im adding it now

Answer (score 2):

You should refer to your app to use that URL because Django doesn't know to which app your URL name belongs to by default. So it'd be something like `<button href="{% url 'appname:uploadupdate' uploads.upload_id  %}" type="submit" class="edit" formmethod="POST">Edit</button>`. Of course make sure that your project's `URL Configuration` includes your app's URLs. Hope it helps.

### UPDATE

From the Django Documentation:

```py
...
class ContactView(FormView):
    template_name = 'contact.html'
    form_class = ContactForm
    success_url = '/thanks/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.send_email()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**Notes:**

- FormView inherits TemplateResponseMixin so template_name can be used here.
- The default implementation for `form_valid()` simply redirects to the `success_url`.

So you should edit your View.

Comment: i tried using using url instead of path but for some reason it isn't working. But for this case i cant even manually go to the upload page much less use the button

I get a type error saying __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: @pfn it sounds like there's a problem with the upload page itself, not just with the url to it. Maybe ask a separate question about the type error?

Answer (score 0):

dont do this in your forms , Use it for getting the Fields from the models and the view allows you to connect your forms directly with your page you can directly print our data in a page so there is an example  :

My models i have Question and ansewer attribute :

------ models.py ------

```
class Question_cours(models.Model):
    quest = models.CharField(max_length= 200 ) ---> question 
    rep = models.CharField(max_length = 20)  ----> answer 

--------- forms.py --------
class Form_question(forms.Form): /// important to make the same name fields 
        quest = forms.CharField()
        rep = forms.CharField()



 -------- view.py ----------


#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
def add_question_cours(request):
    form = Form_question()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Form_question(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid() :
        Question_cours.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)
    else : 
        print(form.errors)

    return render(request , 'bootstrap/add_question.html',context)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

-----------urls.py------------

```
  path('dfsdf',views.add_question_cours,name='add_question')
```

-----------------add_question.html----------

```html
<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
<div class ="form-group">
{{ form.as_p}}
</div>

<button type =" submit" class="btn btn-danger ">
<i class ="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
```

for more information 
https://youtu.be/uz5gyXemak0

Comment: I'm using it in a sort of a menu page , will this work if the page uses many forms?

Comment: i think  you forget method="POST" in your form